# Directly get key or value from a single element hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

If I know there is only one key/value pair in a hash, is there a direct way to retrieve *either* the key or the value directly without having to get all the keys or values?

here is a simple example:

```
hsh1 = {a: 1} 
hsh2 = {a: 2}
hsh1.keys # => [:a]
hsh2.values # => [2]
hsh1.values + hsh2.values # => [1,2]
```

Is there a way to get this instead?

```
1 + 2 # => 3
```

Comment: How does your Hash looks like? Are they have same key? like `hsh1 = {a: 1}
hsh2 = {a: 2}`

Comment: oops I accidentally left the hash out. sorry!

Comment: please give it there...may be you would get better solution,if the hash looks like that one I suspect:))

Comment: I haven given my answer,what I suspect,you have exactly the same Hash object.. :))

Comment: Your question is actually very interesting, +1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
hsh1 = {a: 1}
hsh2 = {b: 2}

hsh1.values.first + hsh2.values.first # => 3
```

Comment: thanks, i believe your answer may be the most direct.

Comment: While I have had to use this type of answer maintaining code, there's always a smell to the underlying data when I have to do that. Having multiple single element hashes makes me think there's something wrong in the data structures or retrieval method.

Comment: @theTinMan, I thought someone might bring that up, that the underlying data structure should change.  I like the coupling of the key,value pair but would also like to get at the value quickly/directly.  Any suggestions? Are there any standard Ruby options?

Comment: IMO, if they are only name/value pairs, treat them as two-element arrays. Hashes are nice until they get in the way; Their value breaks down at this point. @SergioTulentsev is a smart guy, so he's probably got some good ideas how to streamline this too. Add some sample code to your question showing how you create the hashes and maybe we can help.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I don't really have any examples on hand, I just recall there being situations where I have data that conceptually are best associated by hash pairs.  I put them in a hash its lovey-dovey until I need to operate on them, then its exactly like you say, in practice its a pain.

Answer (score 3):

You could inject the addition:

```
(hsh1.values + hsh2.values).inject(:+)
```

Comment: thanks, i see there's no bracket like syntax for this.  I like the 'inject' but I thought calling first could be more direct. I could be wrong though.

Comment: While this works, I'd prefer to see a more direct use of `+`. There's really nothing gained using `inject(:+)` but readability is reduced. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @theTinMan: I assumed OP actually had multiple values in his actual hashes, and simplified the problem for SO. Admittedly wrongly, since he preferred Sergio's answer. :-)

Comment: I think you're definitely on the right track if there were more hashes to add to the array. I'd have used: `[hsh1, hsh2].inject(0) { |i, h| i += h.values[0] } => 3` but that's to DRY up the array and do the value accessing in the block. Sergio's answer would break down quickly if there were more than two hashes to access. And, really, this demonstrates a problem with SO, because often we're left to assume too much about the question or data. As is though, yours is a nice clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

As every good Rubyist, you should have your private library of refinenments:

```
module MyStuff
  refine Hash do
    def key
      msg = "Method ##{__callee__} called on non-singleton hash!"
      keys.tap { |x| x.size == 1 or fail TypeError, msg }.first
    end

    def value
      msg = "Method ##{__callee__} called on non-singleton hash!"
      values.tap { |x| x.size == 1 or fail TypeError, msg }.first
    end

    def merge *args
      return super unless args.empty?
      Class.new BasicObject do
        def initialize hsh; @hsh = hsh end
        def method_missing sym, *args
          super unless args.size == 1
          @hsh.merge args.first do |_, a, b| a.send( sym, b ) end
        end
      end.new( self )
    end
  end
end

using MyStuff

hsh1 = {a: 1} 
hsh2 = {a: 2}
hsh1.key #=> :a
hsh1.value + hsh2.value #=> 3

wrong_hsh_1 = {}
wrong_hsh_2 = {a: 1, b: 2}
wrong_hsh_1.key #=> TypeError
wrong_hsh_2.value #=> TypeError
```

Allows even

```
( hsh1.merge + hsh2 ).value
( hsh1.merge - hsh2 ).value
( hsh1.merge * hsh2 ).value
( hsh1.merge / hsh2 ).value
```

Comment: those are some nice helper functions, and I learned some syntax too. thanks!